# put css inside templateURL directive

Tags: css, directive

is it good put css inside templateURL directive? or is better split in files,

for example:

Directive file:

```
.directive('btn', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/form/btn.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope, $attrs) {

      }
    };
  })
```

template file: btn.html

```
.custom-input-file {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-input-file .input-file {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}


<div class="custom-input-file icons ng-binding"><input type="file" size="1" class="input-file" />
                upload file
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

99.99% of the time I separate all css to different `.css` files according to buttons, navs, typography, specials etc.. and never inline or *inhead*.

Personally I can't think of a good reason to keep it inline or *inhead*, it also makes maintaining harder in general having to look in `.html` files for css.